# Save SQL Server filestream data into temporary Access 2010 table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2010, attachment, filestream

thanks for you time!

**Problem:**

I want to save the filestream data from my back end into a temporary table in my front end.

**Context:**

- Front End - Microsoft Access 2010
- Back End - SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (FILESTREAM enabled to level 3)

I've just migrated an Access 2010 Back End to a filestream enabled SQL Server 2008, no problems. As part of that migration I converted the Access 2010 'attachments' columns into filestream enabled `varbinary(max)` columns.

The SQL Server instance is properly configured  for filestream i.e. I can access the files stored using filestream through t-sql in SSMS.

I know how to establish a connection with the SQL Server Instance from within Access 2010.

*I don't know how to access the filestream data (the file name, file type and file data) from within Access 2010.*

When I have accessed the filestream data I plan to convert it back into the multi-valued 'attachment' field within a temporary table in the Access 2010 Front End, as I can then continue to use the built in attachment features of Access 2010.

Performance isn't a huge concern as this Access 2010 Front End is only used by <15 users and will soon be replaced by a RoR web application.

**Pseudo Code of what I want to do:**

```
Set adoCMD = New ADODB.Command
Set adoCon = New ADODB.Connection
adoCon.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=[ServerNameOmitted];Database=[DatabaseNameOmitted];Trusted_Connection=True;"
Set adoCMD.ActiveConnection = adoCon

Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
adors.open "BLAH BLAH BLAH"
--'Need a query here which allows me to access all the filestream data for a file

--'Once accessed and set to an ADORS.Recordset, I can loop though and convert back to Access 'attachment' format
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Patrick